# sub- & supersolution problem from Kuttler

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Lately, I've been trying to read through one of the chapters of Kuttler's 'Reaction-Diffusion equations and applications'. I got to theorem 16 (chapter 5), page 49, which basically says that : 
If $\lambda_0 > -k$ (where $\lambda_0$ is the principal eigenvalue of Laplace operator), then  
 
$u_t = \triangle u + ku(1-u)$ in $\Omega \times (0,\infty)$  
$u = 0 $ on $\partial \Omega \times (0,\infty)$  
possesses at least one nontrivial nonnegative steady state solution.

I can understand how the sub- and super solution are constructed, yet the reference to theorem 13 is a bit vague to me. For one thing, in theorem 13 we constructed the sub-/supersolutions so that they converge to the steady state solution. Here we already have them, but they certainly do not converge to the steady state (supersolution is '1', and subsolution is $\delta \psi$, where $\psi$ is principal eigenvector). Hence, i do not see the analogy the author is pointing at. 
One another thing i was looking at was chapter 9.3 in Evans' 'Partial Differential Equations'. Theorem 1 of this chapter deals with the existence of such a solution (though i did not go through the proof yet), but the differential equation in question lacks $u_t$. If some generalization existed, it would instantly solve the original problem. Could anyone give a reference to some generalization of this theorem if it exists? Any help will be much appreciated.